# How to capture outgoing packets going through a specified Ethernet port (e.g. eth0) using Netfilter?

Tags: netfilter

I was wondering how I can capture packets going through a specified ethernet port (e.g. eth0) using Netfilter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the rule to the OUTPUT chain that has the ULOG target, for example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p TCP --dport 25 -j ULOG
```

The ULOG target is not terminating target, i.e. the chain traversal continues from the next rule.

Then, you can log the captured packets in different ways using [ulogd](http://netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/index.html) daemon or look at it's source code to implement your own treatment.